# SQL Server Profiler not available in Sql Server Management Studio tools

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

SQL Server Profiler is not available in Sql Server Management Studio tools for a few users.
They can run Profiler as a seperate application but can't find this app in SSMS. Do you know what can be a reason?

[image: Screen]

Comment: What version of SQL server? What version of SSMS?

Comment: Considering that profile is deprecated, and has been for quite some time, wouldn't they be better off using XE anyway? Otherwise, I suspect they have (in error) removed it. you can readd the link in the Customize menu.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that profile is deprecated, and has been for quite some time, wouldn't they be better off using Extended Events anyway?

Otherwise, I suspect they have (in error) removed it. You can readd the link in the Customize menu.

Right click the toolbar and select Customize:

[image]

Select the Commands Pane, and then change the Menu bar drop down to Tools. Then find the point you want to add the Command (by default above Database Engine Tuning Advisor) and then select "Add Command" and add SQL Server Profiler:

[image: ![enter image description here]